# Java AWT and Swing: How to design like in CSS

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hello I'm new to Java when it comes to ui/gui. My question is, how do you design the java awt/swing like in CSS? I saw some codes like setBackground and setForeground but I dont know the rest. I want to do it by code rather than using a gui builder or whatever you call it because that is where I'm comfortable. Thank you in advance

Edit:
I'm sorry if there is some misunderstanding. I want to design java like in css which uses code rather than a gui builder but still I want to use java than css to design java application

Comment: Use [JavaFX Applications with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)

Comment: Nimbus provides CSS like customisation, but you have to appreciated, Swing was around before CSS was popular

Answer (score 2):

Although you are asking about Swing, if you want to style with CSS, I HIGHLY recommend using the JavaFx Library, which had built in CSS support to style.

Comment: This is not an answer..it should be a comment

Comment: I'm sorry if there is some misunderstanding. I want to design java like in css which uses code rather than a gui builder but still I want to use java than css to design java application

Answer (score 0):

you can use Builders
for example

```
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
```

can also be created this way

```
BorderPane pane = BorderPaneBuilder()
    // TODO change size, add other components
    .create();
```